# Java script - change style of ASP.NET label on Page_Load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using an Java applet on a page (an upload files applet). After I press Upload command of applet the Page_Load handler is reached. There (in Page_Load handler)I am trying to change an asp:label style from display:none to display:block, (or rise an alert using:

```
     ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Test", "alert('" + "Something to          display" + "');", true);)
```

but is not working...I am newbie with web programming... please give me a hand in understanding what's going on and what solution to try.

here is my code:

```
    if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["User-Agent"] == "MyUploader/1.16"))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        sb.Append("window.document.getElementById(\"testLabel\").className = \"shown\");");
        sb.Append("</script>");
        //
        if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("TestArrayScript"))
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TestArrayScript", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: Hum, Everything looks good... (1) Try checking for errors generated on your browser, also (2) on the browser view the source code to check that the script is actually there...

Comment: I hate to say this but the script is there and in Java console no error was found. I checked also logs from inetpub/wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

Try ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript instead

Comment: Also have with the above have you added a ScriptManager tag to your front end?